# Reverse a number using String builder in java

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

Problem Statement: Given a 32-bit signed integer, reverse digits of an integer.

Example 1:

Input: 123
Output: 321
Example 2:

Input: -123
Output: -321

My Solution:

```
class Solution7{
public int reverse(int x) {
    if(x>Integer.MAX_VALUE || x<Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
        return 0;
    }


    StringBuilder S_rev = new StringBuilder();
    String S_r_v=S_rev.append(Math.abs(x)).reverse().toString();//.toString() String builder to String

   double reverse_no=Double.parseDouble(S_r_v);

    if (x < 0) {
        return -(int)reverse_no;
    }
    return (int)reverse_no;

}
```

}

My Solution is ok for most of the test case. But it cannot pass one test case and I got a error

`Error`: **Line 10: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8463847412-"**

If someone know what type of error it is please discuss.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Two helpful questions for you: Does the exception message indicate the input string is a number? What does the test case test that is different from the others?

Comment: you need to remove the - from the reversed string. another solution is you do the char reversal yourself in the string builder by swapping all numbers but leaving any - in place. then simply parse that result back and it will preserve any sign

Comment: There's no point checking `if(x>Integer.MAX_VALUE || x<Integer.MIN_VALUE)`. It is impossible by definition.

Comment: You can't reverse any int and necessarily get a valid int. Some will be out of bounds.

Comment: it's a problem with how Math.abs handles Integer.MIN_VALUE.  See my answer.

Comment: @khelwood Agree. Value is already coming as an integer. It should throw error when trying to call the method with invalid value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to pass in Integer.MIN_VALUE

When you pass in the minimum integer value, Math.abs seems to return a negative number as stated here

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#abs-int-

```
 Note that if the argument is equal to the value of Integer.MIN_VALUE, the most negative representable int value, the result is that same value, which is negative.
```

You can either check for `x<=Integer.MIN_VALUE` and return 0 if x is Integer.MIN_VALUE or handle the special case for Integer.MIN_VALUE

```
 if(x== Integer.MIN_VALUE)
      return -8463847412;
```

Comment: In my code block `if(x>=Integer.MAX_VALUE || x<=Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
            return 0;
        }` I think this portion handle the overflow. But I got this error:`Input:
1534236469
Output:
2147483647
Expected:
0` So my output does not match with expected output.

Comment: When you reverse 1534236469, it is larger than Integer.MAX_VALUE(2147483647), so it looks like you need to do a check similar to `if(x>=Integer.MAX_VALUE || x<=Integer.MIN_VALUE)` before returning.

Answer (score 1):

By converting number to `String` and reversing the sign symbol ended up on the end of the value. This makes the number invalid.

You don't have to convert to `String` or `double`. You can use module operator `%` to extract digits:

```
public int reverse(int x) {
  long result = 0;
  while (x != 0) {
    result *= 10;
    result += x % 10;
    x /= 10;
  }
  if (result > Integer.MAX_VALUE || result < Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(); // overflow
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you necessarily want to implement it using `StringBuilder`, here it is:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    ReverseNum reverseNum = new ReverseNum();
    System.out.println(reverseNum.reverse(-123));
    System.out.println(reverseNum.reverse(123));
    System.out.println(reverseNum.reverse(0));
  }

  public int reverse(int x) {
    int res = 1;
    String xStr = String.valueOf(x);
    StringBuilder builder = null;

    if (xStr.startsWith("-")) {
      builder = new StringBuilder(xStr.substring(1));
      res = -1;
    } else {
      builder = new StringBuilder(xStr);
    }

    return res * Integer.valueOf(builder.reverse().toString());
  }
```

Output:

```
-321
321
0
```

P.S. If you want to avoid integer overflow, then you can simply use `long` instead of `int`, like this:

```
  public long reverse(int x) {
    long res = 1;
    String xStr = String.valueOf(x);
    StringBuilder builder = null;

    if (xStr.startsWith("-")) {
      builder = new StringBuilder(xStr.substring(1));
      res = -1;
    } else {
      builder = new StringBuilder(xStr);
    }

    return res * Long.valueOf(builder.reverse().toString());
  }
```

Comment: it's not integer overflow, it's with how Math.abs handles Integer.MIN_VALUE

Comment: In my code I don't use Math abs. From the error message "Error: Line 10: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "8463847412-"" First "-" in the end of the number. Second even without "-", "8463847412" is more then Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Comment: The input to cause the error was -2147483648 or Integer.MIN_VALUE.  When you pass in Integer.MIN_VALUE to Math.abs() it returns a negative value and that is what is causing the issue.  See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ReverseString {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    ReverseString rs = new ReverseString();
    System.out.println(rs.reverse(-84638));
    System.out.println(rs.reverse(5464867));
  }

  public long reverse(int number) {

    boolean isNegative = number < 0;

    StringBuilder reverseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String reversedString = reverseBuilder.append(Math.abs(number)).reverse().toString();
    long reversedStringValue = Long.parseLong(reversedString);

    if(isNegative) {
      return reversedStringValue * -1;
    } else {
      return reversedStringValue;
    }
  }
}
```

This code provides the output you have mentioned in the requirement. And It also supports for integer overflow. Your requirement is to convert int values. It is okay to get the converted value in the higher format since converted value may not be in the range of int. I have changed the reverse method return type to long.

I have identified a few issues in your code.

```
public int reverse(int x) {
if(x>Integer.MAX_VALUE || x<Integer.MIN_VALUE) {
    return 0;
}
```

Above code segment, not point of checking whether the value is inside the int range because it is already received in the param as a string. It should throw an error before executing your code lines since it is not able to fit the larger value to int variable.

Finally, the int number you have used is not in the int range. (-8463847412)

Comment: The int number he is using is -2147483648 or Integer.MIN_VALUE. When you pass in Integer.MIN_VALUE to Math.abs() it returns a negative value and that is what is causing the issue. See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
public class ReverseNumber {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(reverse(123456));
        System.out.println(reverse(0));
        System.out.println(reverse(-987654));
    }

    private static int reverse(int i) {
        final int signum;
        if(i < 0) {
            signum = -1;
        } else {
            signum = +1;
        }

        int reversedNumber = 0;
        int current = Math.abs(i);

        while(0 < current) {
            final int cipher = current % 10;

            reversedNumber = Math.addExact(Math.multiplyExact(reversedNumber, 10), cipher);
            current = current / 10;
        }

        return signum * reversedNumber;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
654321
0
-456789
```

This solution avoids strings and can handle negative numbers.
It throws an Arithmetic exception if an integer overflow happens.